Flutter - How to overflow item from appbar to body or vice-versa
In my app I have an appbar with a gradient background and a body with a list of itens wraped in Expanded. I want to place a search field between appbar and body, but I don't know how. I tried to use Stack but when it is positioned beyond the limits of body or appbar the overflowed areas are not shown in screen. How can I place this search field?
My appBar and body are the following:
    appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  flexibleSpace: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          //Color(0xFF0C003A),
                          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        ],
                        stops: const [
                          0.0,
                          0.69,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      shadows: [
                        Shadow(
                          color: tonsDeAzul[12],
                          offset: const Offset(0, -8),
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      decorationColor: tonsDeAzul[12],
                      decorationThickness: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                  centerTitle: false,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  actions: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.comment_outlined,
                          color: tonsDeAzul[12],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Open messages");
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -25,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    child: StandardSearch(
                  textController: _searchController,
                  label: "Pesquisar por palavra ou código",
                  onSubmit: () {},
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
    body: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
            child: clients != null
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 24,
                          horizontal: 16,
                        ),
                        child: StandardSearch(
                          textController: _searchController,
                          label: "Pesquisar por palavra ou código",
                          onSubmit: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: clients.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final item = clients[index];
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  openPedidoDialog(item, cubit);
                                },
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    clientCard(item, context),
                                    const Divider(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                : const Text("Não foi possível encontrar clientes"))




class SearchIntheMiddle extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchIntheMiddle({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: context.screenHeight * .05,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
              ),
              height: context.screenHeight * .15,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF4F709C),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Search Bar Example",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.message,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top:
                (context.screenHeight * .15) - (context.screenHeight * .07 / 2),
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: context.screenHeight * .07,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15,
              ),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: const Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
                  hintText: "Search in middle",
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

The key of the answer is Stack && Positioned widgets.

First, use Stack as body of Scuffold
Use Container wrapped with Positioned as custom appBar
Wrap the TextField with Positioned
Give the it distance from top top : (context.screenHeight * .15) - (context.screenHeight * .07 / 2), 
as you can see (context.screenHeight * .15) is the height of the custom appBar and (context.screenHeight * .07 / 2) is the height of the TextField divided by 2, so you can center the TextField between the abbBar  && the body.
Make sure that the body is Positioned

Extra info
Each of the child of the Stack widget is just a Layer in the screen, so if you want to put widget above another then use Stack && position it with Positioned widget, but remember that the order of the children is important, in this example if you put TextField then appBar then appBar will cover the TextField.
